# How to set title for grouped iOS notifications?

Tags: ios, notifications, title

I recently updated my app's display name to "Cricket Quiz". When I get a push or local notification, the title of the notification itself matches the display name, but the overall title which is used to group notifications together is still showing the old name "ICC Cric Quiz".

[image]

I can't see the old display name anywhere in my project, where would this "batch title" value be set?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem is due to iOS somehow retaining the old app name, presumably from the bundle id. 
Installing on a fresh device which had never installed the game before showed the correct app title (which means users will not be see the old name once the game is released).

Comment: I can confirm(iOS 8.3) that `Bundle Display Name` is all that is needed to change the app's title(both below the icon and the for the grouped notification title). I had to uninstall the app from my iPad, restart it, then clean and rebuild my project from xcode to get the change reflected.